# WinPE Auto-Execute Windows 10 Install (VIA PEX)

Tags: windows, winpe

I've got a question about WinPE, is there a way I can make it so when I boot VIA PEX, select the WinPEx64, it starts at

```
X:\Sources\System32>
```

then I run;

```
net use V: \\Server\Share\Folder
cd /d V:\
setup
```

That's very long winded to start the installation, is there anyway to make it so as soon as I select the WinPE it automatically boots into the 'setup' installation?

Comment: Why not just run '\\Server\Share\Folder\Setup` and skip the mapping of V:?

Comment: It's still avoiding my question. Is it possible to automate it?